# AWS ECS Task Error -- Insufficient GPU resource available

Tags: amazon-web-services, gpu, amazon-ecs

I got the following error on an AWS ECS cluster, with launch type EC2, when I publish a service which has a task (desired count 1)  with the next GPU requirements :

```
    "resourceRequirements": [
            {
              "type":"GPU",
              "value": "1"
            }
    ]
```

Error message :
**service XXXXXXX was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements.
The closest matching container-instance YYYYYYYYY has insufficient GPU resource available.**

The EC2 instance attached to the cluster is p2.8xlarge has 8 GPUS, which should be enough for my requirements.

Any help or information about how ECS computes these requirements is welcome.

Thanks